# How to verify if a window of another program is minimized?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

How can I do this? I've tried `IsWindowVisible()` but that doesn't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check whether a window is minimized, use `IsIconic(HWND)`.

Answer (score 0):

`windowsx.h` has `#define IsMinimized(hwnd) IsIconic(hwnd)`

Thus the answer is `if (IsMinimized(hwnd)) { }`